# Gross Substitutes under continuous perturbations

Tags: economics

Let $v_i(S)_{i \in [n], S \subseteq G}$ be a collection of Gross Substitute valuations.  I am wondering if I can add a small perturbation to each valuation and still get Gross Substitute valuations.  Essentially, is there a small interval for each valuation where it remains to satisfy Gross Substitutes?

Comment: Could you provide a definition of the gross substitute property?

Comment: Sure.  We say a set of valuations obeys gross substitutes if the following holds: Let $p$ be any price vector over elements in $G$ where $p(S) = \sum_{g \in S} p_g$ and for any player $i \in N$ we have $D_i(p) =  \arg max_{S\subseteq G}\{v_i(S) - p(S) \}$.  For a set $S \in D_i(p)$, any $p' \geq p$ (coordinate wise) there is a set $T \subseteq G$ such that $S \cup T \backslash P \in D_i(p')$ where $P = \{g \in G: p_g < p_g' \}$